# Source of chapter

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I came accross a chapter of some book about "quadrilaterals" and I would like to know what book / document it originates from.

Here is the link to the said chapter [link](http://edituradp.ro/site_img/downloads/2013/01/pt_download.pdf)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book should be

AN INTRODUCTION TO QUADRILATERAL GEOMETRY

By Ovidiu T. Pop, Nicu¸sor Minculete, and Mih´aly Bencze
Editura Didactica Si Pedagogica, R. A., Bucuresti, 2013.
300 pp. ISBN 978-973-30-3324-0.

---

One possibility to find out something like this is to take a chapter title / some sentence, that doesn't sound too general and just google it, often you will find it out then.